# Boundary of an open, bounded and convex set in $\mathbb{R} ^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-topology, plane-geometry, differential-calculus

Let $U$ be an open, bounded and convex set in $\mathbb{R} ^n$. Since $\partial U$ is a rectifiable set it follows that up to a set of $H^{n-1}$-measure zero $\partial U$ is contained in a countable union of $C^1$ manifolds, where $H^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ Hausdorff measure.

My question is, weather $\partial U$ itself is contained in a countable union of $C^1$ manifolds?

I think it should be true, since we can apply a generalization of the three strings lemma to show that at only countably many points of $\partial U$  there is not a unique supporting hyper-plane. However, I'm having trouble translating this idea to a formal proof, and I'm begining to doubt weather it is indeed true.

Your help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your statement "at only countably many points of $\partial U$ there is not a unique supporting hyper-plane." This seems to fail for the union of two cones, since at any point of the equator there is a family of supporting hyperplanes. What is the three strings lemma?

Comment: You are right, this triviality (evidently) escaped me. Thanks. Anyway, the three strings lemma is the unofficial name for the lemma that proves that a real convex function is co-countably differentiable  (similar to Theorem 3.2 in Chapter 3 of Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis").

Comment: A simpler counterexample to that statement would be any polyhedron. For the main statement, have you tried the convex hull of a Cantor set along a curve like $(t,t^2,t^3)$?

Comment: Actually, if you just take any convex domain on the plane whose boundary $F$ contains a dense set of "corners", notice that the intersection of $F$ with any compact piece of a $C^1$ curve has no inner points (in the topology of $F$), and apply Baire, you are done with the question, as posed, already. Still, my feeling is that there should be some meaningful way to modify it...

Comment: OP, although the rectifiability result is not hard and well-known, I am having a hard time finding the reference to cite. Could you please help me with it?